# SonarQube rule to disallow 'forbidden' files

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

Is there a way to get SonarQube to raise a violation if certain files/folders are found in source?

For example, specifically-named configuration files which contain sensitive data (e.g. passwords) should not be included in version control, and neither should IDE-specific configuration directories like IntelliJ's ".idea" and Eclipse's ".settings" folders.

(Side-note: I'm aware these can/should be part of a global ignore in version control - but that's not what I'm asking about)

I'd like SonarQube to raise a violation during analysis if any of a set of files/folders exist, preferably using a regex-or-similar pattern to do the checking.

I've read up on the fact that SonarQube plugins can be written in Java, but this seems such a simple concept (and one I'm sure isn't unique) that I'm a little surprised I haven't been able to find any existing rules or plugins. The closest I've found is [sonar-text-plugin](https://github.com/gjd6640/sonar-text-plugin), though that focuses on file contents rather than whether files exist at all.

Before I go reinventing the wheel, is there something pre-existing which could offer this?

SonarQube version 4.5.7 - upgrading is an option if there's no other route.

Comment: anyway I would suggest to upgrade to 5.6.1 the current [LTS version of SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/). You will have then access to the last version of our analyzers, which have seriously leveled up their game : ) (yes, I'm biased)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do confirm that there is no such built-in feature in SonarQube.

You may be want to write a [custom rule](http://docs.sonarqube.org/x/dzFq) for the java plugin.

Comment: Not the answer I was _hoping_ for, but it doesn't get much more authoritative than an answer from the SonarSauce team! Thanks guys.